# Rails JQuery sending GET instead of POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been stuck on a rails issue for a few days and haven't been able to find a solution. My code used to work, but there were some major changes (Required) to the javascript and it no longer works.

My users can attend and withdraw from an event. This takes the user making a button click and then sending a post request, but for some reason the request is processed as a Get request and and fails because there is no route for a get request (needs to be post).

View:

```
    <% if @competition.users.exclude?(@user)  %>
      <%= link_to 'Attend Competition', attend_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

routes.rb

```
  resources   :competitions do
    post 'attend', on: :member
  end
  resources   :competitions do
    member do 
      post 'withdraw'
    end
  end
```

controller:

```
def attend
@competition = Competition.find(params[:id])
if @competition.users.include?(current_user)
  flash[:error] = "You're already attending this competition."
elsif current_user.daily == []
  flash[:error] = "You must have a working device to compete."
else
  current_user.competitions << @competition
  flash[:success] = "Attending competition!"
end
redirect_to @competition
end


def withdraw
p "WITHDRAWING"
@competition    = Competition.find(params[:id])
p @competition
attendee = Attendee.find_by_user_id_and_competition_id(current_user.id, @competition.id)
if attendee.blank?
  flash[:error] = "No current attendees"
else
  attendee.delete
  flash[:success] = 'You are no longer attending this competition.'
end
p attendee
redirect_to @competition
end
```

the actual error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/competitions/9/withdraw"):
```

Thanks

** EXTRA **

Complete show.view

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <%= @competition.title %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Length:</b>
  <%= @competition.length %>
</p>
  <b>Start:</b>
  <%= @competition.start.strftime("%d %m %Y") %>
</p>
  <b>End:</b>
  <%= @competition.end.strftime("%d %m %Y") %>
</p>
<p><strong>Attendees: </strong>
    <% if @competition.users.exclude?(@user)  %>
      <%= link_to 'Attend Competition', attend_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
    <% end %>
</p>
<% a = 1 %>
<% for attendee in @competition.users %>
  <p2><strong><%= a %> </strong><%= link_to attendee.name, attendee %></p2>
  <% if attendee.daily != [] %>
   <p><%= attendee.daily.first(7).sum %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% a = a + 1 %>
<% end %>
</br>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_competition_path(@competition) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', competitions_path %>
```

HTML output from Rails

```
<a href="/competitions/4/withdraw" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">Withdraw</a>
```

** MOAR **

complete errors from the logs

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/competitions/6/withdraw"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/Marcus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Marcus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Marcus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/Marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

HTML from Browser:

```
<a href="/competitions/3/withdraw" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">Withdraw</a>
```

FULL PAGE [could be long]:

```
<html><head>
<title>BOTB</title>
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript">    </script><style type="text/css"></style>
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
<meta content="Cl7ar8gwVcRsJzrKjp92KB6p6PihvVu0jAwngi18dWU=" name="csrf-token">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

  <style id="clearly_highlighting_css" type="text/css">/* selection */ html.clearly_highlighting_enabled ::-moz-selection { background: rgba(246, 238, 150, 0.99); } html.clearly_highlighting_enabled ::selection { background: rgba(246, 238, 150, 0.99); } /* cursor */ html.clearly_highlighting_enabled {    /* cursor and hot-spot position -- requires a default cursor, after the URL one */    cursor: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--cursor.png") 14 16, text; } /* highlight tag */ em.clearly_highlight_element {    font-style: inherit !important; font-weight: inherit !important;    background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--yellow.png");    background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position: top left; background-size: 100% 100%; } /* the delete-buttons are positioned relative to this */ em.clearly_highlight_element.clearly_highlight_first { position: relative; } /* delete buttons */ em.clearly_highlight_element a.clearly_highlight_delete_element {    display: none; cursor: pointer;    padding: 0; margin: 0; line-height: 0;    position: absolute; width: 34px; height: 34px; left: -17px; top: -17px;    background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--delete-sprite.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 0px; } em.clearly_highlight_element a.clearly_highlight_delete_element:hover { background-position: -34px 0px; } /* retina */ @media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {    em.clearly_highlight_element { background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--yellow@2x.png"); }    em.clearly_highlight_element a.clearly_highlight_delete_element { background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--delete-sprite@2x.png"); background-size: 68px 34px; } } </style><style>[touch-action="none"]{ -ms-touch-action: none; touch-action: none; }[touch-action="pan-x"]{ -ms-touch-action: pan-x; touch-action: pan-x; }[touch-action="pan-y"]{ -ms-touch-action: pan-y; touch-action: pan-y; }[touch-action="scroll"],[touch-action="pan-x pan-y"],[touch-action="pan-y pan-x"]{ -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y; touch-action: pan-x pan-y; }</style></head>
  <body style="">
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="/" id="logo">Battle Of The Bands</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav " id="menu">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/competitions">Competition</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/users/1">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/devices">Connect Device</a></li>
                <li><a href="/competitions/new">Create Competition</a></li>
                <li><a href="/users/1/edit">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/signout" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
    <div class="container">
      <p id="notice"></p>

<p>
  Tester March 8
</p>

<p>
  <b>Length:</b>
  5
</p>
  <b>Start:</b>
  03 03 2014
    <p></p>
  <b>End:</b>
  03 03 2014
<p></p>
<p><strong>Attendees: </strong>
      <a href="/competitions/3/withdraw" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">Withdraw</a>
</p>
  <p2><strong>1 </strong><a href="/users/1">Marcus Smith</a></p2>
   <p>49774</p>
<br>


<a href="/competitions/3/edit">Edit</a> |
<a href="/competitions">Back</a>

      <footer class="footer">
  <small>
    by <a href="http://www.twitter.com/_mhsmith_"> Marcus Smith</a>
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
      <!-- <pre class='debug_dump'>--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
action: show
controller: competitions
id: '3'
    </pre> -->
    </div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you share the resulting HTML for the Withdraw link?  If Rails is doing its thing, it will be a form.  Incidentally (and probably just a copy/paste thing) you don't have an **end** in your view.  Just mentioning because everything looks right, so we have to look for the odd stuff.

Comment: Added the extra information. Hopefully this helps

Comment: got any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: I just posted the entire error. Didn't see any javascript errors, but I'm not sure what exactly to look for

Comment: Javascript errors won't appear in your rails log.  You have to turn on the console view in your browser (in chrome you can right click, inspect element, then go to the "Console" tab and then refresh the page).  Javascript errors will appear in the console

Comment: Followed your steps (learned something new), but things happened to fast to read (Flashed in console). I recorded my screen and this is what it said. `GET http://.../4/withdraw 404 (Not Found)`, but it doesn't mention specific javascript errors. `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead`, I don't think this is important and was on every page.

Comment: By the time you see "GET http... 404 (Not Found)" the issue is already past.  That means that the link is not being interpreted by jquery_ujs.  Just load the page and **don't** click on the Withdraw link.  Javascript errors affecting things would show before clicking the link.

Comment: The text in the console is that `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead`

Comment: Please, share the resulting HTML from the browser so we can make sure that rails is generating the correct FORM tag with the parameters you provided.

Comment: Updated question with html from browser

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you don't have jquery_ujs.js included.

```
// application.js
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

In your application.js manifest, you should be including jquery_ujs - it't the unobtrusive javascript code that will transform the GET request into a POST because of the `data-method` field in your  tag.

If you **do** have jquery_ujs.js included,m then sevenseacat's remark about javascript errors is probably it - if you have any javascript errors that are being raised before the jquery_ujs.js is executed, it will not be able to interpret your link.

Comment: I include jquery_ujs in my application.js file. I just included the entire error from the log, maybe that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone will see this since a lot of time has elapsed since the question was asked but I was encountering the same issue so if anyone is looking for an answer and jquery-ujs wasn't the issue, here's what finally solved it for me - double check your code and make sure you **do not** have:

`$(document).unbind('click')`...

anywhere in your code. This causes the needed javascript Rails uses to convert a GET request into a POST or DELETE request to not run. Hope that helps solve this issue that bugged me for a  very long time for someone else.